# Laravel unit test: method get/post is undefined

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I'm trying to create a unit test, but even simple code like this

```
$response = $this->get('/');
$response->assertStatus(200);
```

returns

```
1) Tests\Unit\BookTest::test_adding_book
Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Unit\BookTest::get()
```

Comment: What is your BookTest extending?

Comment: @AneesSaban extends TestCase

Comment: Which TestCase? I'm wondering if you're using Laravel's or PHPUnit's.

Comment: I did PHPUnit's one

Answer (score 0):

Comment or remove "use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;" and add "use Tests\TestCase;"